# jquery Form Validation uses GET when I've specified POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have an email form that needs to be validated using jquery. I can't use the inbuilt HTML5 attribute since the form will be submitted by a JS function to avoid reloading the page.
The form validates fine. But when it is submitted, the data is sent as a GET request.
If i remove the validation the from the JS function, the data is sent as POST and everything works perfectly.
Also, and this isn't a problem (just curious), when i try to validate a single form element the other form elements are automatically validated too.
For example, I have a field for name and for email. If i try to validate only the name, the email gets validated too. A bit curious as to why that happens.
Here is my JS code:
    var main = function() {

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() { 

    // $('#form')[0].checkValidity();
    // $('#form')[1].checkValidity();
    // if(!$('#form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    //   code here
    // }
    // if(!$('#form')[1].checkValidity()) {
    //   code here
    // }

    // var form = $('#form');
    // form.validate();
    // if(form.valid()) {
    //  //code here
    // }

    // if ($('#name').val.equal('')) {          //even this causes the same problem!!
    //  return;
    // };
    // if ($('#email').val.equal('')) {
    //  return;
    // };

    // if( document.form.name.value == "" )
    // {
    //  alert( "Please provide your name!" );
    //  document.form.name.focus() ;
    //  return;
    // }

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var number1 = $('#number1').val();
    var number2 = $('#number2').val();
    var company= $('#company').val();
    var designationText= $('#designationText').val();
    var message = $('#message').val();

    var messageToSend = "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nLandline: " +    //have to use double quotes since PHP detects  
        number1 + "\nCell Phone: " + number2 + "\nCompany: " + company +            //escape sequences like \n only in double quotes
        "\nDesignation: " + designationText + "\nMessage: " + message;

    var dataString = "Name=" + name + "&Email=" + email + "&MessageToSend=" + messageToSend;

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "php/mail.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('.form').hide()
          $('#changingText').text("Thank you. We will be in touch with you shortly " + name)
        }
    });

    return false;

});
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I have tried all the commented out ways to validate the form data and then submit it to the PHP script. But I keep having the same problem. The data is sent as GET.
Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h4 id="changingText">Enquiry Form</h4>

            <form class="form" id="form" action="" method="" role="form" autocomplete="on">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="name" id="name" placeholder="First & Last name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="number1" id="number1" placeholder="Landline number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="number2" id="number2" placeholder="Mobile number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Company Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designationText" id="designationText" placeholder="Designation">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" autocomplete="off">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="6" cols="10" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

So what I'm basically trying to do is validate the form using jquery and if all the data is valid, send it to the PHP script (using POST) as shown. If I leave this stuff commented, everything works perfectly, but there is no validation.
Sorry if my code isn't too good. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Try using a `return false;` instead of just `return;`

Comment: Besides that, I think that `$('#name').val.equal('')` should be `$('#name').val() === ''`

Comment: @devqon The second comment solved part of the problem! :)
That is, the data is now being sent as POST. However, it gets sent even if the data is invalid. A notification is displayed saying that the data is invalid but it skips to the remaining part and sends the invalid data anyways.
Doesn't work even if its put in an else{}. It gets executed anyways.
Any ideas why that may be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attaching a click event handler to the submit button, try attaching a submit event handler to the form itself. This will allow you to handle the `submit` event and stop the form from submitting any unvalidated data via `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(ev) {

    // prevent from auto-submitting  
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();

    // validate; if something is wrong handle it;
    if ($('#name').val() === "") {
        alert("You don't have a name? :(");
        return;
    }

    // if all is good, then submit.
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "php/mail.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('.form').hide()
          $('#changingText').text("Thank you. We will be in touch with you shortly " + name)
        }
    });

});
```

`return false;` is supposed to do exactly what `ev.preventDefault();` and `ev.stopPropagation();` do, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit. :)